# Add marker to Google Map on Click

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm struggling to find a very simple example of how to add a marker(s) to a Google Map when a user left clicks on the map.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

After much further research, i managed to find a solution.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
   placeMarker(event.latLng);
});

function placeMarker(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location, 
        map: map
    });
}
```

Answer (score 49):

In 2017, the solution is:

```js
map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
});

function placeMarker(position, map) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map
    });
    map.panTo(position);
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting upvoted in 2022, so I guess this is still working 

Answer (score 22):

This is actually a documented feature, and can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#EventArguments)

```
// This event listener calls addMarker() when the map is clicked.
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
  });

  function placeMarker(position, map) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map
    });  
    map.panTo(position);
  }
```

Answer (score 19):

To make the user able to add only once, and move the marker; You can set the marker on first click and then just change the position on subsequent clicks.

```js
var marker;

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
   placeMarker(event.latLng);
});


function placeMarker(location) {

    if (marker == null)
    {
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: location,
             map: map
          }); 
    } 
    else 
    {
        marker.setPosition(location); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Currently the method to add the listener to the map would be

```
map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
});
```

And not

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
});
```

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#EventArguments)

Answer (score -1):

The best method to add marker 'on-click' is:

```
map.addListener('click', function(event) {  
    addMarker(event.latLng);  
  });
```

Comment: This simply repeats all the other answers.